# An estimate for $|e^{-n\int_{0}^ta(s)ds}-e^{-n\int_{0}^tb(s)ds}|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $T>0$ fixed number, $a(t),b(t)\in C[0,T]$ and $a(t)>0$, $b(t)>0$, Consider the difference $|e^{-n\int_{0}^ta(s)ds}-e^{-n\int_{0}^tb(s)ds}|$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$. By using Mean value theorem one can easily show that:
>
> $$|e^{-n\int_{0}^ta(s)ds}-e^{-n\int_{0}^tb(s)ds}|\leq nT\max\limits_{t\in[0,T]}|a(t)-b(t)|.$$

**My Question:** Do you have any suggestion to obtain an estimate for the above difference such that which not depend on the positive integer $n$. In other words an estimate like

> $$|e^{-n\int_{0}^ta(s)ds}-e^{-n\int_{0}^tb(s)ds}|\leq C\max\limits_{t\in[0,T]}|a(t)-b(t)|,$$

where $C>0$ may depend on $T$ but not $n$.  Please help me, I have really no idea to find such an estimate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such an inequality. To make things simpler I will show that the inequality
$$
e^{-nA}-e^{-nB}\le C(B-A),\quad 0<A<B,
$$
does not hold for any constant $C$. Take $A=1/n$, $B=2/n$. Then $e^{-nA}-e^{-nB}=e^{-1}-e^{-2}$, while $B-A=1/n$.

It is not difficult to see that
$$
e^{-nA}-e^{-nB}\le\min\Bigl(1,\frac BA-1\Bigr),\quad n\in\mathbb N,\quad0<A<B.
$$